# why we require uint64_t when unsigned long is available ?

Tags: c, typedef, type-conversion

I just wanted to know, Why we need to have `uint64_t` which is actually a `typedef of unsigned long` , when unsigned long is anyway available. Is it only for make the name short or any other reason ?

Answer (score 9):

The reason should be pretty obvious; it's a guarantee that there is 64 bits of precision. There is no such guarantee for `unsigned long`.

The fact that on *your* system it's a `typedef`, just means that on *your* system `unsigned long` is 64 bits. That's not true in general, but the `typedef` can be varied (by the compiler implementors) to make the guarantee for `uint64_t`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not always a typedef for `unsigned long`, because `unsigned long` is not universally 64 bit wide. For example, on x64 Windows, `unsigned long` is 32 bit, only `unsigned long long` is 64 bit.

Answer (score 1):

Because `uint64_t` means a type of exactly 64 bits, where `unsigned long` can be 32 bits or higher.

On a system where unsigned long is 32 bits, it would be used to typedef `uint32_t` , and  `unsigned long long` would be used to typedef `uint64_t`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does make it shorter, but that's not the *only* reason to use it. The main motto of using this `typedef`-ed data types is to make a code more robust and portable accross various platforms.

Sometimes, `unsigned long` may not be 64 bits, but a definition of `uint64_t` will always gurantee 64 bit precision. The typedef of `uint64_t` can [ read as : will] be varied accross different platform to have a precision of 64 bits.

Example:

1. for systems having `long` as 32 bits, `uint64_t` will be typedef to `unsigned long long`
2. for systems having `long` as 64 bits, `uint64_t` will be typedef to `unsigned long`

Comment: `unsigned long` is already not-64-bit *today*, on x64 Windows for example.

Comment: Actually `unsigned long` wasn't 64bit for a *long* time...

Answer (score 0):

Not only to make it shorter, but also to make it more descriptive.

If you see in code `uint64_t` it will be easy to read as `unsigned int of 64 bits data type`.